# Override one private property in one Swift Mailer class (Symfony2)

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, swiftmailer

I am writing a Symfony2 bundle which requires Swift Mailer. I use Composer to require Swift Mailer and Composer is used to install the bundle.

I want to change the value of one private property in one Swift Mailer class.

Of course I could just change the property in the PHP code, but I want a much better solution that ensures when my bundle is installed (Composer) there is no other manual work involved (i.e. manually changing the property in the PHP code).

I don't think Swift Mailer is a Symfony bundle, so I don't think I can use a compiler class.

I know I can configure Composer settings, but I don't think this is the solution. The issue of course is that I can't change any of the Swift Mailer code (hence a Compiler pass would be great).

I don't think this is even possible, but surely I am able to do this without manual work every time my bundle is installed?

Comment: More details my be useful as that is one thing that is not easy to do without modifying the code.

Comment: You can use Reflection but it's doubtful that you actually need to change the property.  Update your question with some more details.

Comment: The need to change a private property usually is wrong. You miss to see alternative solutions, and you didn't provide details of what you want to change, so nobody can advise better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just can't, and this is the behavior of PHP in general.

A private property means that it's not an extension point provided by SwiftMailer.

What is your desired use case? If your use case is a valid one, and there is no other usable extension point for that, I'd suggest you to contribute to SwiftMailer to propose it. (The easiest contribution would be to make the property protected)